# Heroku 'H12' request timeout error with Node JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, ejs

I have deployed a Node js app on Heroku and I get the error H12 request timeout when I try to launch it. Not sure what is wrong with my app.js file. I am using node, express, and ejs for templating. Maybe I have a lot going on in my GET method. Any help with H12 error will be appreciated.

My Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const ping = require('ping');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    var Data = [];
    const hosts = [
        '8.8.8.8',
        'nibbler',
        '10.204.2.14',
        'nic-bqnbnntkwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'co-omaha-wired-qqrrbzpgwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'co-austin-cjjbbdqcwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'fctx-wired-vtwpbhcgwq.dynamic-m.com',
        '172.16.10.1',
        'fc-greenwood-dzrrbnzqwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'fcpa-3400-wired-nndkzwnrwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'fcpa-chrome-gwmjjghjwq.dynamic-m.com',
        'fcga-wired-bjkwtcjqwq.dynamic-m.com',
    ];   

    for(var i =0; i<hosts.length; i++){
        ping.promise.probe(hosts[i]).then(function (resp) {

            const destination = ['Azure DC','FC Nevada','Google DNS', 'Austin', 'Omaha', 
            'FC Greenwood', 'FC Georgia', 'FC Pennsylvania 3500', 'FC Pennsylvania 35400', 
            'FC Dallas', 'Nibbler DNS', 'NIC'];

            if(resp.alive){
                const input = {
                    "Destination": "",
                    "Host": resp.host,
                    "Status": "Alive",
                    "Avg": resp.avg
                }
                Data.push(input);
            }
            else {
                const input = {
                    "Destination": "",
                    "Host": resp.host,
                    "Status": "Dead",
                    "Avg": resp.avg
                }
                Data.push(input);
            }
            if(Data.length == 12){
                Data.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var A = a.Host.toUpperCase();
                    var B = b.Host.toUpperCase();
                    return (A < B) ? -1 : (A > B) ? 1 : 0;
                });
                for(var i = 0; i<destination.length; i++){
                    Data[i].Destination = destination[i];
                }
                res.render("home", {data: Data});
            }   
        });
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: H12 means it the request times out. I tested locally and changed at the and of the code `res.render("home", {data: Data});` to `res.send({data: Data});` and it took the server 5sec to send, which is not the end of the world. I would deploy the application this way and try to examine the response. If you receive the proper data back without this timeout error, you should doublecheck the res.render function.

Comment: But how should I render the home ejs file then?

Comment: I meant it just for debugging purposes. Try if you can get something back from the service through heroku.

Comment: hi! did you fix the issue. I have similar issue. my code is working locally, however heroku gives me h12 error

Answer (score 0):

An H12 means it takes more than 30 seconds for your app to finish responding to the request. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout

It could easily take more than 30 seconds to ping all those hosts. Have you timed it in a development environment?

On heroku long running tasks should be run on a worker dyno. In this case a worker could periodically ping those hosts and write the results to some kind of data store (redis or postgres). The web app would simply pull the results from the data store and render the page.

Heroku has some good documentation here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-redis-workers

Comment: Normally when I run the app locally, it takes literally 2 seconds to load the page.

Comment: I don't have much experience with node. Can you show me how will my program look like as a worker dyno?